# Using a HTML5 Theme in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, angular, ng2-bootstrap

I am wondering how can i set up my current Theme that is designed using bootstrap and some css and js

I am using following css and js files in my theme and i don't want to put it in index.html like we did in angular 1 can any one tell me how to import all css and js effectively without compromising Angular 2 structure and behaviour.

```
<link href="assets/plugins/pace/pace-theme-flash.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="assets/plugins/boostrapv3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="assets/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="assets/plugins/jquery-scrollbar/jquery.scrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link href="assets/plugins/bootstrap-select2/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link href="assets/plugins/switchery/css/switchery.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link href="theme/css/theme-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link class="main-stylesheet" href="theme/css/theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="theme/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Js files

```
 <script src="assets/plugins/pace/pace.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/modernizr.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/boostrapv3/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-easy.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/jquery-unveil/jquery.unveil.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/jquery-bez/jquery.bez.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/jquery-ios-list/jquery.ioslist.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/jquery-actual/jquery.actual.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/jquery-scrollbar/jquery.scrollbar.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/bootstrap-select2/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/classie/classie.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/switchery/js/switchery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/jquery-validation/js/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I tried using ng2-bootstrap and bootstrap but can not get it working.

Comment: I followed up this guide https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/blob/development/docs/getting-started/ng-cli.md but bootstrap classes have no effect it seems it is not loading css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is your loading straight bootstrap along with jquery plugins instead of a something like angular-ui-bootstrap. Some boostrap stuff uses pure CSS(no compatibility issues) and others use jquery/ which can work iffy with Angular1/2 sometimes hence projects like angular-ui-bootstrap.

---

try the angular 2 version https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/
then load all the css files using webpack(just putting in the same css folder the current project css files are). Obviously you would need to change the existing bootstrap javascript code to angular-ui directives.